# Pixelmator 2.0 Features

Tags: applications, image-editing, macos

I've just started using Pixelmator 2.0, and I love it. It's a beautiful alternative to clunky and overbearing Adobe products, but I can't seem to find some very simple key features that I'm sure (read: hope) must exist.

- Center Horizontally/Vertically in Background
- Inner Shadows
- Transform Tool (I know that `CMD+F` brings up a transform mode, but is there a tool that can be docked in the toolbar?)

Aside from the latter, which is a UI preference of mine, these features seem (to me at least) to be pretty critical in a full-bodied image editor.

**EDIT**: If these things are stock-and-standard features, has anyone out there found at least a workaround for them?

Comment: You do realise Pixelmator has an [official support forum](http://support.pixelmator.com/viewforum.php?f=3) too?

Comment: Yeah. They've been acceptably helpful, but there a few things that I'd like to get some second opinions on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- How to center horizontally / vertically for text: [extend the bounding box](http://support.pixelmator.com/viewtopic.php?t=6626&sid=e8f5cbeb86e758352ed6d55d845ea38d).

  Unfortunately, I couldn't find any way to do this for other items! I am actually surprised I didn't find it very limiting myself. There are several snapping options, but even when activating “Layers” (not active by default), the snapping happens only on edges, not on center (and it is very small, not as easy to manipulate as in the iWork suite, for example).
  [image: Pixelmator Rulers Preferences]
- Tutorial for [Inner Shadows on Pixelmator](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FnWOoHUa7k) on YouTube (it's a workaround that consists of duplicating layers). Made with / for Pixelmator 1, but I couldn't find more info for Pixelmator 2.
- In Pixelmator 2, you can choose which tools you want to add to the toolbar. Unfortunately, the Transform tool is not offered. [image: Pixelmator Tools Preferences]

  However, as you outlined yourself, the Transform tool is just one keyboard shortcut away. You'll have to resolve to <kbd>⌘F</kbd>.

Comment: No go on the inner shadow tutorial, but the forms were helpful enough for that. Could you explain magnetic rules a little bit? The forum you linked to was not particularly explanatory. And regarding CMD+F: it just seems incongruous to me to make most things dockable tools, and some things just... not... That's merely a UI preference though.

Comment: @pcperini Thanks for challenging me about the magnetic rulers: I had read too quickly, did not realize it worked only for text and expected it to expose the same behavior as most Apple programs regarding snapping. I'm afraid Pixelmator does not really suit your needs, which is too bad since it is a really lovely app to use.